# Unmarshalling []byte json data in []string

Tags: go

**What do I want**: compare two json files "line-by-line" (more explanation below).

**How json files look like**:

```
{
    "key": {},
    "key2": {},
    "key3": "val",
    "key4": [],
    "key5": [
        "k": {}
    ]
}
```

In general, I do not know actual JSON structure.

Assume I have two indented json files. Under "line-by-line" comparison I mean I want to know, that row 2 from `1.json` and row 2 `2.json` are not equal.

`1.json`:

```
1 {
2     "k": "val"
3 }
```

`2.json`:

```
1 {
2     "k": "vaaaaal"
3 }
```

My problem is that I can't unmarshal json directly to `[]string`.

Initial json data is stored in `[]byte`, I'm getting it from AWS S3 using [Downloaded](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/#Downloader.Download), `jsonData` variable is an object of [WriteAtBuffer](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/aws/types.go#L162)

Currently I'm only able to unmarshal json into `map[string]interface{}` or `interface{}`, but it will be hard to convert `map[string]interface{}` to `[]string`.

Comment: Unmarshaling into a value of type `interface{}` should always succeed if the input is valid JSON. Can you show us a [mcve]?

Comment: @icza sorry, my bad. I've checked my code and there is no error while unmarshalling into `{}interface`. So, json is valid.

Comment: @Tarasovych is there a specific reason why you're using json to unmarshal the data? If all you want is to compare line by line do you need to unmarshal the data? Couldn't you just simply read each line of both files and compare them, just as you would with a plain text file?

Comment: @mkoprive *Couldn't you just simply read each line of both files* - I couldn't, because I'm getting plain json, and it does not have any line breaks. So it's one-line file, if we can say so.

Comment: I don't know how you ended it with that in indented JSON, care to share? It gives me proper indented JSON: [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ks5Q668uADg).

Comment: Also please note this is not valid JSON: `{"key":{},"key2":{},"key3":"val","key4":[],"key5":["k":{}]}`, the last array part is invalid, if array contains objects, they should be wrapped in `{}`.

Comment: If jsons is one-line file, why not just compare them byte to byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I've ended up with this approach, but I'm not sure it's the best.

```
var out bytes.Buffer
err := json.Indent(&out, jsonData.Bytes(), "", "  ")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
outStr := out.String()
slice := strings.Split(outStr,"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to compare the exact field's match. So you can try using `map[string]string{}`

Here is an example

```
   var jsonMap = map[string]string{}
   var json = []byte
   json = // get your json bytes here
   json.Unmarshal(json, &jsonMap)

   // Access your field's value
   fmt.Println(jsonMap["key"]) 

   // If you want slice, convert values from map to string slice
   slice := mapToSlice(jsonMap) 

   func mapToSlice(jsonMap map[string]string) []string {
       slice := make([]string)
       for _, value := range jsonMap {
          slice = append(slice, value)
       }
       return slice
   }
```

Comment: `map[string]string{}` is not suitable in my case, because json could contain array of arrays or object of objects